# Is it safe to delete the stuff in the folder "$Recycle.Bin" on each drive?

Tags: windows, recycle-bin

I have been regularly cleaning up my computer and noticed a folder named "$Recycle.Bin" on each of my drives. I understand that this folder is used for the recycling feature on Windows, but I am not sure if it is safe to delete the contents of this folder (not the folder itself). Can anyone provide information on the purpose of this folder and if it is safe to delete the contents of this folder without causing any issues with my computer or the recycling feature? Additionally, is there a recommended method for doing this? Any information or guidance on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are files you deleted.

Yes, it is safe to delete files in the Recycle Bin on each drive.

> Can anyone provide information on the purpose of this folder

The purpose is to hold files you delete for your review, so once again, you deleted the files and if you do not need them, it is safe to delete the files.

This will not harm Windows in any way.

In future it will be worth your while to review and empty all Recycle Bins on all drives.